# Scala turn comma delimited string to Array

Tags: scala

I have a string that looks like the following:

`"1,100,53,5000,23,3,3,4,5,5"`

I want to simply turn this into a Array of distinct Integer elements. Something that would look like:

```
Array(1, 100, 53, 5000, 23, 3, 4, 5)
```

Is there a `String` method in Scala that would help with this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
scala> "1,100,53,5000,23,3,3,4,5,5".split(",").map(_.toInt).distinct
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 100, 53, 5000, 23, 3, 4, 5)
```

Obviously this raises an exception if one of the value in the array isn't an integer.

edit: Hadn't seen the 'distinct numbers only' part, fixed my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Another version that deals nicely with non parseable values and just ignores them.

```
scala> "1,100,53,5000,will-not-fail,23,3,3,4,5,5".split(",").flatMap(maybeInt => 
    scala.util.Try(maybeInt.toInt).toOption).distinct
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 100, 53, 5000, 23, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

added type checking for the string being parseable as Int :

```
package load.data

object SplitArray {

  def splitArrayintoString(s: String): Set[Int] =
    {
      val strArray = s.split(",")
      strArray filter isParseAbleAsInt map (_.toInt) toSet
    }

  private def isParseAbleAsInt(str: String): Boolean =
    str.forall(Character.isDigit(_))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, if you expect items that can't be cast, you might want to use [`String::toIntOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option[Int]) in order to safely cast these split `String`s to `Option[Int]`s and eliminate them with a `flatMap`:

```
"1,100,53s,5000,4,5,5".split(',').flatMap(_.toIntOption).distinct
// Array[Int] = Array(1, 100, 5000, 4, 5)
```